# Normalised cumulative energy difference

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I need to recreate these two equations in Matlab. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/01vSV.png)

The goal is to use them to detect peaks for a spike sorting algorithm using using a normalised cumulative energy difference (NCED). E<sub>tot</sub> is the total energy of the signal and E(t) is the normalised cumulative energy for segments of the signal. The algorithm detects peaks when the value of the first derivative of E'(t) is greater than 1. The data I have is 20 seconds of EMG data taken at 2000 Hz sampling frequency.

I've tried two methods so far. Both have utilized the trapz or cumtrapz functions. The first method was just to recreate the equations the best I could and iterate over the entire signal to define which point has a peak.

```
% NCED
% total energy of the signal including noise
Etot = trapz(T,V1_filt.^2);
% Find normalized cumulative energy difference
En = cumtrapz(T,V1_filt.^2)./Etot;
% define peaks
pksmaxNCED1 = zeros(size(pksmaxog1));
locsmaxNCED1 = zeros(size(locsmaxog1));
for n = 1:length(En)
    if diff(En) > 1
        pksmaxNCED1(n) = pksmaxog1(n);
        locsmaxNCED1(n) = locsmaxog1(n);
    end
end

pksmaxNCED1(pksmaxNCED1 == 0) = [];
locsmaxNCED1(locsmaxNCED1 == 0) = [];`
```

The second involved using findpeaks to find all local maximum values and their locations and then examining a window around those peaks.

```
% iterate over all peaks and verify if En is greater than 1
pksmaxNCED1 = zeros(size(pksmaxog1));
locsmaxNCED1 = zeros(size(locsmaxog1));
% select window around spike
win = 10; %5 ms on each side each 2 data points is 1 ms.
for n = 1:length(locsmaxog1)
    if locsmaxog1(n)-win >= 1 && locsmaxog1(n) + win <= length(V1_filt)
        spike =locsmaxog1(n)-win:locsmaxog1(n)+win;
        mag = V1_filt(locsmaxog1(n) - win : locsmaxog1(n) + win);
        En = trapz(spike,mag.^2);
        % for m = 1:length(spike)
        %     En(m) = cumtrapz(spike(m),mag(m).^2)./Etot;
        % end
    end
    if diff(En) > 1
        pksmaxNCED1(n) = pksmaxog1(n);
        locsmaxNCED1(n) = locsmaxog1(n);
    end
end

pksmaxNCED1(pksmaxNCED1 == 0) = [];
locsmaxNCED1(locsmaxNCED1 == 0) = [];
```

Both methods resulted in no peaks found. My E<sub>tot</sub> value is always much larger than the energy of individual peaks.

Comment: Create `d = diff(En);` outside the loop and inside the loop instead of writing `if diff(En) > 1` use `if d(n) > 1`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I've implemented the change; however, it is still not resolving my issue with identifying zero peaks in the whole signal.

Comment: Couldn't you use [findpeaks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html)?

Comment: Much earlier on in the code I use findpeaks to create the locsmaxog and pksmaxog vectors in this section of code. This section of code aims to identify which of those peaks are neural pulses.

Comment: I cannot understand what you are trying to do. Could you please provide a minimal working example with small inputs and the expected outputs so we can reproduce the expexcd data. For example You can write : "I have [ 2 4 3 1 5 3] and I want [ 5 3 4 2]".

Comment: Say you have signal data like the following, [0,0.5,0.7,0.5,0.7,0.5,5,1,0.7,3,0.5,0.7,0.5,0.7,0.5,0], using findpeaks will show peaks at the hypothetical noise values of 0.7 as well as the 5 and 3 data points. [0.7 5 3 0.7 0.7]. I want to use the two posted equations to use normalized cumulative energy to identify only the peaks that have energy above the level of the hypothetical noise signal. Which would be only [5,3].

Comment: I recognize I can do this with thresholds in this simpler version, but this project is part of a larger one comparing different spike selection methods.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the example because I dont know `T` and `V1_filt`. However this `intersect(find(diff(En)>1), locsmaxog1)` should return the positions of those requested peaks.